# Question put on hold by moderators. Why was that since question has not met an answer?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

It was me who asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964836/remove-character-from-a-string?noredirect=1#comment31493955_20964836) question. It was a duplicate but it had not satisfied any solutions of the original question. I mentioned it over comments and even then it was put on hold. A lot after that I found my exact solution over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992702/replaceall-function-not-working-while-removing-special-character). So why was that put on hold even when it's not solved?

Comment: It wasn't closed as a duplicate, nor was it put on hold by a moderator. That was done by 5 users with the [close vote privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions). The reason they voted to close is written in the close reason: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist" – chrylis, devnull, Brian Roach, SK9

Comment: @jmac I know.But I had mentioned my attempts as comments for the answers.

Comment: @crv When posting a question please remember to include your effort in the question itself.  Don't hold it up for posting it in comments.

Comment: @devnull I had also mentioned the attempts as direct comments to the question. I read from help center that comments to questions can be provided to give more clarity to the questions.It means not everything needs to be provided questions right. If one needs to answer he is supposed to read the comments too of the question right?

Comment: @gnat that was a good resource that you provided.But its not the specific case I asked.

Comment: @crv Comments are also supposed to be temporary and are easily missed. If people came by to review your question for reopening later, you would have much better success if all of the details are in your question. Also, having a complete question would benefit other people with a similar problem arriving on your question via a search engine. (The same is true for clarifying details in an answer.)

Comment: @Troyen yeah i got you. I will try to take care of that from now.

Comment: @crv It seems like people don't quite understand what you're doing and why it's not working.  If you included an example of what you were parsing (in the question) and added the part of your code where you were doing the parsing (in case you had some other mistake people could spot), you may convince the community to give your question another shot.  Editing your question will automatically place it under community review.  For more, I recommend reading [this advice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215544/what-guidance-should-we-give-people-asking-unclear-questions-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: Comments can be used to clarify, not for posting code.

Answer (score 6):

Comments are like post-it notes. They are for temporary information like clarifications. If you have important information that will help people answer, that information should be edited in to the body of your question.

If you edit your question while it is [On Hold], it will automatically be put in the reopen queue, and users will be able to review it to see if it should be opened again based on the edit you made.

I suggest that you add the comments to your question, make sure that it is clear what you are asking about, and then hope the community reopens it. Here are some resources that may help you ask better questions:

- [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)
- [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)
- [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)
- [Meta discussions on asking questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asking-questions)
- [How to ask questions the smart way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) — long but good advice.

Answer (score 0):

I voted to close the question because it's invalid; `String#replaceAll()` works just fine with backslash characters. You just have to put the backslash in the string correctly.

Comment: but it doesn't worked for me..I needed to double escape the backslash as it's an escape character in both strings and regex, and the mentioned solution in this question solved my query.